# как использовать slot в router-view? vue3

Tags: vue-router, vue3

есть такой родительский компонент в котором расположен `router-view`:
**IndexSlider.vue**

```html
<template>
...

<router-link :to="{ name: 'index-newsfeed' }" class="newsfeed-more-load__btn btn btn__hover">
    <span>больше новостей</span>
</router-link>

<router-view>
    <span slot="title">последние</span>
</router-view>
</template>
```

и такой компонент который загружается в этот `router-view`: 
**Newsfeed.vue**

```html
<template>
<div class="newsfeed-news">
    <div class="newsfeed-news__title">
        <slot name="title" />
    </div>

    ...
</template>
```

как можно передать в `slot` который в `Newsfeed.vue`, какую нибудь разметку, из `router-view` который расположен в `IndexSlider.vue`(`Newsfeed.vue` естественно должен загрузиться в этот `router-view`)?

роуты:

```js
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'index',
        redirect: '/index'
    },
    {
        path: '/index',
        name: 'index-slider',
        component: IndexSlider,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'newsfeed',
                name: 'index-newsfeed',
                component: Newsfeed
            }
        ]
    }

]
```

код на [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-bas-nr2n2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&view=editor)